# How to create wxWidgets application without external dependencies?

Tags: linux, compilation, dependencies, cross-platform, wxwidgets

Please forgive any non-technical terminology, as I am very new to software development and am still trying to wrap my head around how libraries work and are used.

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 with Cinnamon Desktop.

I downloaded the source code for wxWidgets into a local project folder, and then did as follows (from the base wx directory):

- mkdir buildgtk
- cd buildgtk
- ../configure --with-gtk
- make

(These are the instructions provided in the install.txt that comes with the wxWidgets library).  The first time I attempted this, I got the error stating that the GTK+ development files could not be found.  I used:

> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

to get them, and then retried the installation.  This time it worked.  However, during the execution of the "make" command (which resulted in a lot of code passing through the terminal very quickly, so I didn't have time to copy the exact phrases) several items were displayed that looked something like:

> (nameOfPackage) from where?  (sys)

or something like that.  For example, I believe it said the PNG package, JPEG package, and some other stuff were being pulled from "sys" which I assume means it is pulling from shared libraries on my computer.

If I want to create a truly portable app, how can I compile wxWidgets library without including all these external dependencies?  Any help is very greatly appreciated as I am still trying to understand all the intricacies of the actual compilation process, object files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to link everything completely statically. And unless you link GTK+ itself statically (which is not recommended for technical reasons and also has licensing implications), you also shouldn't link `libpng` used by GTK statically neither.

For the other libraries, e.g. `regex`, `expat`, `lib{jpeg,tiff}`, you can use `--with-xxx=builtin` configure option to statically link with the version bundled with wxWidgets.

In practice, the usual solution is to just build on a rather old system as all the newer ones will be compatible with it.

P.S. configure output is stored in `config.log`, you should also be able to use your terminal scrollback buffer to see the output which went by too fast. And, of course, you can always redirect configure output to `tee(1)` and then use `less` to view it more comfortably.